# Is it safe just use __class__ in a python class definition

Tags: python

I understand __class__ can be used to get the class of an object, it also can be used to get current class in a class definition. My question is, in a python class definition, is it safe just use __class__, rather than self.__class__?

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

class foo:
    def show_class():
        print(__class__)

    def show_class_self(self):
        print(self.__class__)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    x = foo()
    x.show_class_self()
    foo.show_class()
```

```
./foo.py
<class '__main__.foo'>
<class '__main__.foo'>
```

As the codes above demonstrated, at least in Python3, __class__ can be used to get the current class, in the method show_class, without the present of "self". Is it safe? Will it cause problems in some special situations? (I can think none of it right now).

Comment: I'm surprised it resolves the bare reference to `__class__`.

Comment: Actually, I'm surprised too! That is the reason I ask whether it is a common idiom.

Answer (score 1):

That is documented in the datamodel, so I believe it is safe/reliable.

From [*3.3.3.5. Executing the class body*](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#executing-the-class-body):

> Class variables must be accessed through the first parameter of instance or class methods, or through the implicit lexically scoped `__class__` reference described in the next section.

From [*3.3.3.6. Creating the class object*](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#creating-the-class-object):

> `__class__` is an implicit closure reference created by the compiler if any methods in a class body refer to either `__class__` or `super`

It is true that the docs mention any *methods*, your `foo.show_class` is a function but perhaps not convincingly a method. However [PEP 3135](https://peps.python.org/pep-3135/), which added this reference, is worded differently:

> Every function will have a cell named `__class__` that contains the class object that the function is defined in.
> ...
> For functions defined outside a class body, `__class__` is not defined, and will result in runtime `SystemError`.

Answer (score 0):

`__class__` is lexically scoped, whereas `some_object.__class__` is dynamically dispatched. So the two can different when the lexical scope is different from the of the receiver, like if lambdas are involved:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

class ClassA:
    def print_callback(self, callback):
        print(callback(self))
        
class ClassB:
    def test(self):
        ClassA().print_callback(lambda o: o.__class__) # <class '__main__.ClassA'>
        ClassA().print_callback(lambda _: __class__) # <class '__main__.ClassB'>
        
ClassB().test()
```

It depends on what you're trying to achieve. Do you want to know which class's source code region you find yourself in, or the class of a particular object?

And I think it goes without saying, but I'll mention it explicitly: don't rely on the attribute directly, use the `type` function. I.e. prefer `type(o)` over `o.__class__`.

Comment: It's not so confusing if you understand why `__class__` is there in the first place (to allow zero-argument `super()` to work).

Comment: [This](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X1PQ7zzltz4) is a great video on how `super()` works, for anyone interested in what @wim is referencing

Comment: Interesting thing I found: `__class__` produces an `LOAD_DEREF` opcode, not a `LOAD_GLOBAL` (e.g. used for `__main__`) or `LOAD_ATTR`/`LOAD_METHOD` (used for any other attributes/methods)

Comment: Not sure why that's interesting? It's documented as a closure reference and `LOAD_DEREF` is the usual opcode for loading closure vars..

Comment: I also don't think it's quite right to say to prefer `type(o)` over `o.__class__` because in some cases these can refer to different things.

Comment: @wim 1) "LOAD_DEREF is the usual opcode for loading closure vars" I didn't know that, but knowing the opcode was a useful jumping off point for me to find more details about the impl details at work here 2) "because in some cases these can refer to different things." I was under the impression that `type` was the public API, and `__class__` is more of an internal thing you shouldn't be touching (like `setattr` vs `__dict__`). Is that not the case? and when can the two differ?

Comment: That's not exactly the case.  `__class__` is a writable attribute and there is even an example use-case offered in the docs for altering it [here](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#customizing-module-attribute-access). As for when `type(obj)` and `obj.__class__` can be different, that's a natural consequence of the fact that objects can write `__class__` to "lie" about their type. In some cases this is a useful feature. A standard library example using this is [`weakref.proxy`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/weakref.html#weakref.proxy).

Comment: I knew about the proxy/mock use-case, but with those, wouldn't it be better to use `type(the_proxy)` to let it do its job and give you the faked type, rather than its true type? Or did I get it the wrong way around?

Comment: It depends whether you want to believe the lie, or reveal the lie.

Comment: Isn't the point of the proxy, for most intents and purposes, to "believe the lie"? And to be clear, which approach is the one that can be intercepted by the mock "the lie", and which one is the actual ground truth?

Comment: You may want either one for different use-case. Sometimes you even want to know about both (for example the proxy's `__repr__` uses both, returning something like `'<weakproxy at 0xdeadbeef to Foo at 0xcafef00d>`). Anyway, we're drifting off-topic - my main point was that it does not really "goes without saying" to prefer `type(o)` over `o.__class__` like the answer writes.